# Probability question: distance of point from centre of square

Tags: probability

A point 'A' is randomly chosen in a square of side length 1 unit. Find the probability that the distance of A to the centre of the square does not exceed x.

I don't get how to even start the solution. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: what can you use?

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand what you want to ask

Comment: is it homework? did you learn markov inequality yet? other formulas?

Comment: Its not a homework question. No I have no idea about Markov inequality. Actually this question appeared in our maths olympiad question paper

Answer (score 1):

The required probability is the ratio of the area of the circle to the area of the square. [image]

That is $\pi x^2$.

Comment: But how can I prove that or justify that

Comment: And what if $x > \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Yes I was thinking of solving it making various cases: x<0,1/2>x>0 and x>1/2

Answer (score 0):

The point $A$ can be thought of $(X,Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent uniformly distributed random variables.  Taking the square as having diagonally opposite corners $\left(-\frac 12, -\frac 12\right)$ and $\left(\frac 12, \frac 12\right)$, you are asked to compute the probability that $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2} < x$, which works out to be a ratio of
areas. For the case $x < \frac 12$, see the answer by Abishanka Saha. For $\frac 12 < x < \sqrt{1/2}$, you need to compute the area of the intersection of the square and the circle
which is a more complicated calculation than the $\pi x^2$ of the simpler case.

Comment: Well I think I can give it a try using area under curve using integration since I know the equations of the curves.